# Convert Postscript file to XPS

Tags: vb.net, ghostscript, postscript, xps

I need a way to convert a Postscript file to XPS. I'm using VB.net so any method with an API or command-line would be fine. As far as I know Ghostscript can't do it but I would love to be wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ghostscript can do it, but there are severe limitations. You can use the xpswrite device to produce XPS as an output (in a similar fashion to pdfwrite to produce PDF).

However the xpswrite device is much more primitive, it hasn't had much attention paid to it over the years given the lack of interest in XPS. Some pages may emerge being rendered, and some fonts may be bitmapped (XPS only supports TrueType fonts, PostScript has a *much* wider range of fonts).

Etc, etc.

However, since the task will require a full PostScript interpreter I suspect your only other choice is to spend considerable sums of money. I think Global Graphics might have a commercial solution for this, there may be other suppliers but none of them will be open source (or, indeed, cheap).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Here's my use case (Excel > XPS > AddJob and PDF with bookmarks): Ihttp://stackoverflow.com/a/33239717/2559297

Comment: It looks like I'll skip PS > XPS based on your answer.

Comment: The original plan was PS > PDF with bookmark and print via Adobe Reader but I was having severe problems with the print jobs not appearing in the correct order. That's why I was looking at XPS etc.

Comment: Why not just go Excel -> PostScript and then go PostScript to PDF ? I think Excel can also produce PDF natively now, so Excel -> PDF and then PDF->PDF adding bookmarks at that stage.

Comment: I answered in chat: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92986/chat-about-use-case-ps-and-xps

Answer (score 0):

After having researched this and having learned from KenS: It's much better in most cases to print to XPS directly instead of from PS. Any application can print to XPS by using "Microsoft XPS Document Writer" and printing to file.

Answer (score 0):

Use GhostScriptSharp

https://github.com/mephraim/ghostscriptsharp

Happy to Help you!

Comment: This is for converting PDF pages to JPEG?!

Comment: This is a wrapper for Ghostscript, so, Yes, it can be used to convert PDF to JPEG.